# How to change node binary for wallaby on visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, wallaby.js

My wallaby configuration is crashing and I think it's because I'm using the wrong version of node to process my wallaby.config.js file.

I want to change the version of node that wallaby uses, but I'm not sure where that setting is located?

To clarify, I don't want to change the version of node used by the tests, but the version of node used by wallaby to parse the wallaby.config.js file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may specify [the `wallaby.node` setting](https://wallabyjs.com/docs/intro/install.html#nodejs-1) in VS Code settings.